# Generate a SSH pair with AES-256-CBC

Tags: linux, debian, ssh

Okay its easy to create a ssh pair with `ssh-keygen`, but how do I generate with `ssh-keygen` a ssh pair which allows me to use AES-256-CBC?

The default one is always AES-128-CBC, I tried already different parameters but they didn't function like:

```
ssh-keygen -b 4096 -t rsa -Z aes-256-cbc
```

But they didn't work, any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do **not** generate the key used by `aes` when you use `ssh-keygen`. Since `aes` is a *[symmetric cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm)*, its keys do *not* come in pairs.  Both ends of the communication use the same key.

The key generated by ssh-keygen uses [public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) for authentication. From the `ssh-keygen` manual:

```
 ssh-keygen generates, manages and converts authentication keys for
 ssh(1).  ssh-keygen can create RSA keys for use by SSH protocol version 1
 and DSA, ECDSA, Ed25519 or RSA keys for use by SSH protocol version 2.
```

From the `ssh` manual:

```
 Public key authentication works as follows: The scheme is based on
 public-key cryptography, using cryptosystems where encryption and
 decryption are done using separate keys, and it is unfeasible to derive
 the decryption key from the encryption key.  The idea is that each user
 creates a public/private key pair for authentication purposes.  The
 server knows the public key, and only the user knows the private key.
 ssh implements public key authentication protocol automatically, using
 one of the DSA, ECDSA, Ed25519 or RSA algorithms.
```

The  problem with public key cryptography is that it is quite slow.  Symmetric key cryptography is much faster and is used by `ssh` for the actual data transfer. The key used for the symmetric cryptography is generated on the fly after the connection was established (quoting from the `sshd` manual):

```
 For protocol 2, forward security is provided through a Diffie-Hellman key
 agreement.  This key agreement results in a shared session key.  The rest
 of the session is encrypted using a symmetric cipher, currently 128-bit
 AES, Blowfish, 3DES, CAST128, Arcfour, 192-bit AES, or 256-bit AES.  The
 client selects the encryption algorithm to use from those offered by the
 server.  Additionally, session integrity is provided through a
 cryptographic message authentication code (hmac-md5, hmac-sha1, umac-64,
 umac-128, hmac-ripemd160, hmac-sha2-256 or hmac-sha2-512).
```

If you wish to use `aes256-cbc` you need to specify it on the command line using the -c option, in its most basic form this would look like this:

```
$ ssh -c aes256-cbc user@host
```

You can also specify your preferred selection of ciphers in `ssh_config`, using a comma-separated list.  Tinkering with the defaults, is, however, not recommended since this is best left to the experts.  There are lots of considerations and years of experience that went into the choice of defaults by the OpenSSH developers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the cipher used to generate the private/public keys for an ssh connection you can do:

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private.key 4096
ssh-keygen -y -f private.key > public.key.pub
```

see the ciphers available for your ssh connection with:

```
ssh -Q cipher
```

your daemon (sshd - the remote host you're connecting with) also needs to support the type of cipher you're connecting with. I think that the ciphers used on your sshd are the same of ssh also installed in your remote host. So doing `ssh -Q cipher` on your remote host you'll see what ciphers your sshd supports.

PS: If you try to generate the public key with openssl it won't work for an ssh connection not only because it's formatted differently but it also appears to be encoded differently as well. There's [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011572/convert-pem-key-to-ssh-rsa-format) that shows how to convert between the two.